# Python Tkinter Loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make an infinite loop (with a break) that runs alongside my Tkinter window and interacts with widgets on it. Yes, I **have** done my research, but when I run my code and activate the function the window stops responding.

I've deleted the 'while true' from the method, and at the end of it placed:

```
if self.connected:
    root.after(100, self.listenServer(id, req))
```

I think the problem is that the function takes a little while to complete (I'm making an Omegle client, so it has to connect to the server). I can tell that it runs six times, because I put a print statement in the method.

Is there a simple <strike>(AKA no threading)</strike> method to solve this problem?

Well, if threading is the only way to do it, then I guess it would be fine

Here are my connect and listen methods:

```
    def listenServer(self, id, req):
    site = url.urlopen(req)

    #We read the HTTP output to get what's going on
    rec = site.read()

    if 'waiting' in rec:
        self.chatbox.config(state=NORMAL)
        self.chatbox.insert(END, "Waiting...\n", "italic")
        self.chatbox.config(state=DISABLED)

    elif 'connected' in rec:
        self.chatbox.config(state=NORMAL)
        self.chatbox.insert(END, "Stranger connected\n", "italic")
        self.chatbox.config(state=DISABLED)

    elif 'strangerDisconnected' in rec:
        self.chatbox.config(state=NORMAL)
        self.chatbox.insert(END, "Stranger Disconnected\n", "italic")
        self.chatbox.config(state=DISABLED)
        self.connected = False

    elif 'typing' in rec:
        self.chatbox.config(state=NORMAL)
        self.chatbox.insert(END, "Stranger is typing\n", "italic")
        self.chatbox.config(state=DISABLED)

    elif 'gotMessage' in rec:
        self.chatbox.config(state=NORMAL)
        self.chatbox.insert(END, "Stranger: " + rec[17:len(rec) - 3] + "\n")
        self.chatbox.config(state=DISABLED)

def OmegleConnect(self):
    self.chatbox.config(state=NORMAL)
    self.chatbox.insert(END, "Connecting...\n", "italic")
    self.chatbox.config(state=DISABLED)

    site = url.urlopen('http://omegle.com/start', '')
    id = site.read()
    id = id[1:len(id) - 1]
    self.chatbox.config(state=NORMAL)
    self.chatbox.insert(END, "Stranger ID: " + id + "\n", "title")
    self.chatbox.config(state=DISABLED)
    req = url.Request('http://omegle.com/events', urllib.urlencode({'id':id}))
    self.chatbox.config(state=NORMAL)
    self.chatbox.insert(END, "Finding a stranger...\n", "italic")
    self.chatbox.config(state=DISABLED)
    self.connected = True
    root.after(100, self.listenServer(id, req))
```

Yes, I know this is quite inefficient with the way it writes to the text widget. I tried making a method to do it more easily, but it wasn't working. I'll worry about that once I get this up and running.

Comment: Are you asking for a solution that utilises threading now? If so, we are going to need to see more code and know what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, if that's what has to be done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the window needs to be continuously updating in order for the window to react to input - that's a reality of the way the program works, and makes sense.

On the other hand, you want to do something in a loop which doesn't allow the window to update - given this, there is no way for the window to react.

So no, there is no solution to this that won't involve threading or multiprocessing in some way - you need to do two things at once.

## Possible solutions:

If you don't want to deal with threading directly, you could use a library like [`twisted`](http://twistedmatrix.com/) to provide the networking you are talking about, which will avoid you waiting on your request to complete.

The other main option is to use the [`multiprocessing` module](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) or [`threading` module](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#module-threading) to move the things you want to do simultaneously to updating your interface into a new thread/process.

Comment: I'm looking at the multiprocessing module, and I've decided there will be a separate method that is run every so often using Tkinter's 'after' that will communicate with listenServer.

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want to use threading:

```
tkinterwidget.update() # repaint & use events
```

or if you want to schedule something:

```
class MainWindo(Tk):

    ...

    def method(self):
        # do something here for every 100 ms
        if loop:
            self.after(100, self.method)
```

Be careful not to interact with Tkinter from two threads. My Programs sometimes crashed because of this.

Comment: Did you read my entire post? I tried 'after' but since the method takes a while, my program freezes.